# Drop down problem in bootstrap. Can anyone help making it work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a drop-down menu on the top navigation.
I have applied bootstrap to one of my page, however because of this the drop down menu does not work.

Applied to Head:

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Applied to Body:

```
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <div class="topnav-left">
    <a href="/"><img src="Img/Signature-Black.png"></a>
    </div>
    <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="./about.html"> About</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Blog <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="./photos.html">Photos</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

My external CSS for the navigation bar:

```
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 100;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 10%;
}
  
.topnav a {
    float: right;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: 35px;
    transition: 1s;
}

  
  
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 7%;
    top: 30px;
}

.topnav .icon:hover {
    color: #daa520;
}


.topnav-left {
    float: left;
}


/* Dropdown */
.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
  
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500; 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

/* Dropdown + other menu hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    color: #daa520;
    transition: 1s;
}
  
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
  
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
  
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    color: #daa520;
}
  
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}



/* Resize Screen */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .topnav-left {
        float: left;
    }

}
  
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: fixed;
      right: 7%;
      top: 30px;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .topnav.responsive .topnav-left {
        float: none;
    }
    
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
    }
}
```

I am not very familiar with Bootstrap, so I am not exactly sure how it differs from using normal CSS and HTML to create a drop-down list. I hope there is an easy way to fix and keep the applied design for the navigation links, as I don't want to have to rework the site without bootstrap.

I appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!

I have tested other pages, so I know the issue is not with the drop-down itself.
I have also tried removing bootstrap, and it does work without it, but then it will mess up the rest of the contents on the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a conflict between your dropdown and the bootstrap dropdown. "dropdwon" is a class name in bootstrap, it use it both in css and js files.

you can try using bootstarp dropdown and change it's style or use different class name

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that, I changed to "dropdn" instead of "dropdown" to avoid using bootstrap on it, and it works as you said! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Blog <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This section of your code is conflicting with your custom CSS you have written below:

```
    /* Dropdown */
.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
  
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500; 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

/* Dropdown + other menu hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    color: #daa520;
    transition: 1s;
}
  
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
  
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
  
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    color: #daa520;
}
  
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

You cant have custom CSS properties with the same name as Bootstrap selectors, try looking more into Bootstrap and their own pre-built dropdowns, youll find they're much easier to implement and you can make your custom changes to them a lot easier

Comment: Thank you, yeah I am sure it would've been easier to use bootstrap but since I already made the navigation on multiple pages and I only applied bootstrap to a single page it makes more sense to just change the name instead of recreate the navigation in bootstrap for all pages.